# Show that a function from a set is non-conservative

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So I have this question

> There exists some set A = (a,b,c,d), we have a function H from Powerset(A) into
>       Powerset(A) -> {T,F} given by H(X)(Y) = True iff |X|<|Y|
>
> I need to show some subsets X,Y of A which imply that H is non conservative.

I have scoured the internet for example of both conservative and non conservative functions, was able to find some idea of what a conservative function is but have yet to find any actual example (with sets, or just numbers) which show any of these ideas in action.

Do I have to subdivide X into say (a,b) and Y into (c,d) and then go from there? Completely lost here :<

EDIT: adding definition for a conservative function

> Function D from ℘(E) into [℘(E)→X], X any set, is conservative iff for all A,B,B′⊆E,
>       D(A)(B)=D(A)(B′) whenever A∩B=A∩B′.

Comment: You lost me at "from Powerset(A) into Powerset(A) -> {T,F}".... Can you clear up your notation? If not, it may be difficult-to-impossible to answer your question definitively.

Comment: What is your definition of *conservative function*?

Comment: @Cameron from my understanding it just maps the powerset to either true or fasle.

Comment: Could you share with us your idea of what a "conservative function" is? I've never heard that expression, and Google results don't seem to be enlightening.

Comment: @Brian.M.Scott a function is conservative iff for all A,B,B' belonging to set E, F(A)(B) =F(A)(B') whenever A^B=A^B'  but then again thats just words, I have yet to find an actual example similar to above where they show a set A=(a,b,c,d) and step by step show how they got the conservative function definition

Comment: it is incredibly frustrating when the teacher just shows definitions with no simple examples to solidify the concepts :@

Comment: @CameronBuie: It looks to me like $H$ is a function $\mathcal P(A)\to(\mathcal P(A)\to\{\mathsf{true},\mathsf{false}\})$, in other words a "curried" function that takes two subsets of $A$ and produces a truth value. More commonly that would just be called a binary relation on $\mathcal P(A)$.

Comment: @user201451: When you write "A^B=A^B'", what do the "^"s mean? Set intersection?

Comment: @HenningMakholm correct, I added an edit to show a more clear layout of what the definition of a conservative function is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Corrected.**

You have a function $H$ that assigns to each subset of $\{a,b,c,d\})$ a $\{\text{T},\text{F}\}$-valued function on $\wp(\{a,b,c,d\})$. Specifically, $H(X)$ is the function

$$H(X):\wp(\{a,b,c,d\})\to\{\text{T},\text{F}\}:H(X)(Y)=\begin{cases}
\text{T},&\text{if }|X|<|Y|\\
\text{F},&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}$$

You want sets $A,B,B\,'\subseteq\{a,b,c,d\}$ such that $A\cap B=A\cap B\,'$, but $H(A)(B)\ne H(A)(B\,')$; thus, you want one of the statements $|A|<|B|$ and $|A|<|B\,'|$ to be true and the other false. To keep things simple, let’s try for an example with $|A|=|B|$ and $|A|<|B\,'|$.

If we set $B=A$, we certainly get $|A|=|B|$. We also get $A\cap B=A$, so we want $A\cap B\,'=A$ as well. This is equivalent to requiring that $A\subseteq B\,'$. On the other hand, we want $|A|<|B\,'|$, so we really want $A\subsetneqq B\,'$. A very simple example, then, is obtained by letting $A=B=\varnothing$ and $B\,'=\{a\}$, say: $A\cap B=\varnothing=A\cap B\,'$, but $H(A)(B)=\text{F}\ne\text{T}=H(A)(B\,')$.

Any example with $A=B\subsetneqq B\,'$ will show that $H$ is non-conservative.

Comment: hmm both of the questions seem to be making sense, you wrote a much more clear explanation. Thank you

Comment: @user201451: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=\{a,b\}$, $Y=\{a\}$, and $Y'=\{a,c,d\})$. Then $X\cap Y=\{a\}=X\cap Y'$, and $H(X)(Y)=\text{ False }\ne\text{ True }=H(X)(Y')$.

Comment: I wish I could put both answers as "solved" option. Thank you.